# Using TIP120 and common grounds

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, transistors

Good morning all!

Unsure if it's safe to use the approach on the left, connecting ground across the two power supplies rather than the right. I assume it's fundamentally the same thing but just want a secondary opinion.

I'm using a number of tip120s in a project and want to avoid running a bunch of common ground lines to make the wiring as easy/neat as possible.

Any advice on whether the cyan wire on the left is a sound approach to replace the cyan wire on the right?

I Appreciate it!

Justin

[image: tip arrangement]

Comment: SHOW REAL SCHEMATICS!  No, I'm not going to trace thru your crayon drawings to figure out the circuit.  -1 for dumping them on us, and closing because without proper schematics it's too much work to tell what you are asking.

Comment: I love cartoons normally but what's that blue thing in the middle?

Comment: Wow. I'm not asking rocket science here. Get off your high horse.

Comment: Why exactly was this closed as unclear? It's pretty darn obvious what was being asked. Hatred of Fritzing shouldn't be a reason for closing a question.

Comment: I agree, and thank you Tom for answering my question. The whole idea here is exchanging knowledge, not stifling the learning process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both circuits will achieve the result of common ground, but there are some conditions.

Assuming first that you are driving a low current load (e.g. <100mA), and at low frequency (i.e. not PWM), then either circuit would work just fine.

If however you start introducing PWM switching frequencies, then the circuit on the left becomes problematic. Basically the return path for the signal going to the transistor gate is through a large amount of wire and straight through the power supply pins of the Arduino. What this means is that you will end up injecting your control signal as a ripple current. This may not be an issue - for example a MOSFET would be so low current that the ripple would likely go away with adequate decoupling. Also if you aren't doing anything with sensitive Analogue electronics it probably wouldn't be an issue.

The circuit on the left gets around some of this as you are bringing the return path back in close to the pin. However that closeness all depends on how the Arduino PCB is routed - it's possible that that ground pin doesn't go anywhere near the chip initially (it's a two layer board with lots of traces, so the ground plane will probably be broken up).

However lets assume for a minute you are switching a high current load - e.g. 1A through an ultra high power LED. If you wires aren't thick between the power connector and the source (or emitter) of the transistor, then there can be an appreciable voltage drop along the cable (maybe 500mV+). If the load is being switched with PWM, this can result in a very noticeable switching signal on that wire (because the voltage drop in the wire will change with current). If you look at the way *both* of your circuits are drawn, the connection point between the Arduino and the transistor circuit is right by the power connector. This means that any voltage drop caused by the high currents is on the path of the signal - so basically it gets added on to your control signal. I can draw a diagram if you want to illustrate this.

So really, I would say neither of the two are optimal. What I would propose is to modify the one on the right so that the common ground is connected right at the source (or emitter) of the transistor. This means that any voltage drop in the cable caused by the current through the load would not be coupled on to the control signal. When wiring it up, run the wire for the ground, and the wire for the control signal together - you could even twist them together to keep them neat if you wanted to (*).

---

(*) You can DIY twisted wire pairs by putting one end of both wires together in the chuck of an electric screwdriver, hold the other end of each wire in your hand, and then twist it up with by turning on the screwdriver.

Comment: Thank you Tom. For some background, I'm driving two separate arrays of 3W LEDs, no PWM. They both draw ~750ma, and between the power supply and tip120 is a constant current driver. When you say thick, what gauge do you mean? I am going to test the circuit today, and really appreciate your feedback. Are there symptoms I should look for or can measure to determine if the negative effects you described are present?

Comment: @jmwagg Wire gauge is basically the diameter of the wire. The larger the diameter, the larger the cross sectional area of copper, the lower its resistance. How thick depends on length of wire, material (copper, aluminium), and how much voltage drop is acceptable for a given current. For example if your circuit can tolerate a \$100\mathrm{mV}\$ voltage drop on the supply rail, you would need your wire to have a resistance less than \$0.133\Omega\$. There are calculators online for wire thickness.

Comment: For constant current, you're unlikely to see any issue. But I would google 'constant current driver circuit', because the way you have wired the BJT is not as a constant current driver.

Comment: Oh yes, I meant what gauge did you have in mind. I know what gauge is! I left the driver out of the diagram. Thanks again!